# In Backgrond WebRTC offer is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, simplewebrtc, webrtc-ios

In WebRTC i m giving offer when the app is open and working fine and when it goes to background or Phone is unlock offer is not going.How offer can be sent.Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to implement this

**1)** declare your application as `VOIP`. This kind of application is allowed to have one signalling socket working even in background mode; you should use `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler`: method as well in order to keep your socket connection active. As soon as new data will be ready for reading on this socket your application will be awaken and you can send local notification to let user know about incoming call. But this approach is deprecated and isn't battery friendly.

**2)** Simple way is you can just make use of **voip push notifications**.